# Can the product of two different* and non-reciprocal* irrational numbers be rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

This arises from the standard question at the beginning of any basic number theory course: determining whether $ab$ is always irrational, given that $a$ and $b$ both are.

As far as I can tell, the counterexamples to the above statement fall into the following two categories (given $p \in \mathbb{Q}, q \in \mathbb{Q}$):

- $a = b \cdot q \text{ and } b = \sqrt{p}$
- $a = b^{-1} \cdot q$

The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284692/a-twist-in-a-classical-question-sum-and-product-of-two-irrational-numbers-is-r) appear to me to be a case of the latter.

Are there any examples beyond those listed above?

Comment: By definition, the second bullet-point has to cover all ways for $ab$ to be rational with $a,\,b$ irrational.

Comment: $\sqrt8\cdot\sqrt2=2$

Comment: @AndrewChin: $\sqrt(8)=2 \cdot \sqrt(2)$

Comment: @AndrewChin $\sqrt8=4/\sqrt2$

Comment: I will point out that there are more types of irrational numbers than just ones of the form $\sqrt{p}$.  As such, every example falls under the second, and only a few restrictive examples fall under the first (but would also fall under the second)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there aren't. If $ab=q$, with $q\in\mathbb Q$, then $a=b^{-1}q$,

Note that if $a=bq$ and $b=\sqrt p$ for some $p\in\mathbb Q$, then$$a=b^{-1}b^2q=b^{-1}pq.$$Therefore, the first case is a particular type of the second one.